# Posting to Firestore with Custom Token caused Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected ... valid authentication credential

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Final goal: an Angular client receives a token valid for one hour in order to query data from FireStore.

Steps to produce a prove of concept and learn how to work with Custom Tokens:

1 - I created a project in Firebase using firebase tool (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firetestjimis/overview)

2 - I added Firestore database and created a collection. I chose production instead of test because this POC is aimed for security reasons.

3 - I added manually an user in Firebase/Authentication/Add User

4 - I copied User UID from above user added (it is used bellow)

5 - I created a very simple firebase Cloud Function applications in order to answer back a Custom Token. Basically I ran firebase init and added this code in index.tx

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export const getCustomToken = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    if (admin.apps.length < 1) {   //Checks if app already initialized
        admin.initializeApp();
    }
    const uid = "UID mentioned above"; 

    admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
        .then(function (customToken) {
            console.log(customToken.toString);
            response.send(customToken);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
        });
});
```

I reached this by following [other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53138210/4148175)

6 - I succesfully can get a Custom Token from https://us-central1-firetestjimis.cloudfunctions.net/getCustomToken

7 - I can successfully post this Custom Token to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken and get back idTken like

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyCustomTokenResponse",
  "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI ... .... aMorw",
  "refreshToken": "AE0u-Ney9OJ04Z3xA7ACsmI1S637hXeuCTEdaEU9cxhhPnlwh-9q0X7QpSxVRIYdTdrTgXUbS9Q6yUdAWVeXzhGMiLLLHtwSWSoVSWnZs3Gp1Sb050tThNPQiSsSss8GkCigft3PTBkY4nIbRy3A5dA8FHCLbMYQSfKYqvu8To76UyMVCYONJOM",
  "expiresIn": "3600",
  "isNewUser": false
}
```

8 - Now I want to post a simple docuemnt to Firestore collection throw

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/firetestjimis/databases/(default)/documents/transfer' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer /eyJhbGc ... ... iNaMorw' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "fields": {
    "id": {
      "stringValue": "1"
    },      
    "status": {
      "stringValue": "fracasso"
    }
  }
}'
```

and I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

So my main question is: isn't that idToken returned from https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken a valid token to reach the related Firestore?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a forward slash before the ID token in the header that shouldn't be there:

```
--header 'Authorization: Bearer /eyJhbGc ... ... iNaMorw' \
                                ^
```

Comment: thanks, my bad. Now I am getting   "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }. PS. Naturally, I get new Custom Token and post it to googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken again to get a new valid idToken.

Comment: I created a specific question regard "insufficient permissions": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345129/missing-or-insufficient-permissions-during-post-a-document-to-firestore-using-cu